# Can I loop through (public) attributes of a C++ class?

Tags: c++, attributes, iteration

I found the answer for both C Structs and C# classes but came back empty-handed concerning C++.
EDIT : In C, you can't.
In C# it's the GetProperties() method.

**The context**: I have a C++ class with public attributes (let's say a Point with X, Y, Z). I want to send these attributes via UDP to a Java client. My idea was to create a byte (char *) buffer with the three attributes (i took care of the endianness problems).

```
prepareForUdp(char * buffer)
 {
   int offset = 0;
   int offsetValue = 4;
   char tempBuffer[16];  

   memcpy( tempBuffer, &X_, sizeof(X_) );
   offset = offset + offsetValue;
   memcpy( tempBuffer + offset, &Y_, sizeof(Y_) );
   offset = offset + offsetValue;
   memcpy( tempBuffer + offset, &Z_, sizeof(Z_) );
   offset = offset + offsetValue;  

   memcpy( buffer, tempBuffer, sizeof(buffer) );
 }
```

I want my interface to be evolutive, because the point may get a fourth, a five, or an n-th dimension, and I want my prepareForUdp() method to be (relatively) generic.

My question is : how do I loop (or iterate) through my attributes ?

Comment: Perhaps if you posted your 'answer' for C structs, it may illuminate what you consider to be an answer.  I can't see how you would solve it in C and not be able to do the same in C++

Comment: I'm sorry about that, Jamie. The answer for C was "You can't"... I'll edit my first post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no reflection in C++. So, the answer is, you can't :)

Comment: @Isaac: For exactly what you want to do, no, there isn't. You cannot iterate, in any way, through separate members of the class . You can iterate through the bytes though

Comment: That's intersting ! Can you point me to an article or tutorial to do that ?

Comment: @Isaac, to iterate through bytes, you just `reinterpret_cast` the address of your object to `unsigned char*` and iterate through the latter `sizeof(yourObject)` times.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, I'll just figure out myself the best way to do in my case. I'll accept your answer as soon as I can, thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Here's an [article on reflection](http://www.garret.ru/cppreflection/docs/reflect.html) and how to deal with the fact that c++ doesn't do it.

Comment: Thanks, that was instructive !

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.